# How do I reset group index counter

Tags: pdftex, counters

Sometimes I want labels of numbered lists like:

```
Exercise 2.2
  (a)
  (b)
```

For others, I want to display like:

```
Theorem 2.3
  (i)
  (ii)
```

For this end, I add \begingroup and \endgroup and \renewcommand for the group. So the code is like:

```
\begin{example}
\qquad
\end{example}
\begin{enumerate}
\item ...
\item ...
\end{enumerate}

\begingroup\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}
\begin{theorem}
\qquad
\end{theorem}
\begin{enumerate}
\item ...
\item ...
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup
```

This is working, but list index counter can not be reset to (i). The result is actually like:

```
Exercise 2.2
(a) ...
(b) ...

Theorem 2.3
(iii) ...
(iv) ...
```

So I want to know how to reset list index counter in each group.

Comment: `\setcounter{enumi}{0}` at the start of the group? Or use the [`enumitem`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) package, which allows you to do this kind of thing more easily.

Comment: \setcounter{enumi}{0} is working, but the problem is that the rest list index follows that. Is there a way to save the counter number just before Theorem group and restore after the group is over?

Comment: I'm not sure why the `enumerate` environments are outside `example` and `theorem`.

Comment: It is created in SW file and SW may handle latex differently. It should be compatible with latex

Comment: `\newcounter{tmpenumi}` at the start of your file, then `\setcounter{tmpenumi}{\value{enumi}}` and vice versa. But it would be better to put the enumerate environments inside of the other environments as commented. Also Scientific Workplace is technically off-topic on the site.

Comment: @Marijn, thanks a lot. The setback command should be \setcounter{tmpenumi}{\value{enumi}}. You can post it as an answer

Comment: Maybe enumitem package and the resume option might be useful as well.

Comment: Redefining \labelenumi shouldn't affect the resetting of the counter. There is something else going on. Show a complete example.

Comment: @MathWizard these counter commands are just a workaround and not really an answer - and it should not be necessary, the `enumerate` environment normally resets the counter itself. So probably the real problem is elsewhere (some setting in SW for example).

Comment: @Marijn, yes, it is part of a bigger file. The key is that when \labelenumi is used, it is not reset and so the 2nd index label continues from the 1st one. You need to reset yourself. Anyway, a workaround solution is found. Thanks.